# Error creating a new object model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a User model in Rails but when I go inside my rails console and I type User it shows me an error that says "=> User(no database connection)". You can look at the Rails console log below

```
salmanalam@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ cd ..
salmanalam@ubuntu:~/rails_projects$ cd midexam
salmanalam@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/midexam$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
Couldn't load interactive_editor: cannot load such file -- interactive_editor
Couldn't load awesome_print: cannot load such file -- awesome_print
2.0.0-p353 :001 > User
=> User(no database connection) 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > ^C
2.0.0-p353 :002 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a query?

e.g. `User.count`

ActiveRecord probably hasn't tried connecting to the DB yet and hence the message.

> This is NOT a bug. It's the expected behavior. Loading an Active
>   Record model won't establish a connection to the database.

See issue [12804](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12804)